# Not able to do cd /usr/bin/java

Tags: java, linux, unix, root, cd

I am trying to view content of /usr/bin/java directory.But not able to do cd in java directory even if I am accessing as root.

```
/usr/bin# cd java
-bash: cd: java: Not a directory
```

When I am trying to view permission of this directory I am getting this

```
ls -ld java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug  5  2015 java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

What should I do now to access java directory?

Comment: its not Directory pal its link to `java` command

Comment: Try "ls -l /etc/alternatives/java" and check whether it's an existing directory

Comment: as you can see in `ls` output its not a directory, its a soft link to a another file. For seeing the actual path of java directory do `ls -lrt /etc/alternatives/java`

Comment: thank you. Now I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/alternatives/java` usually links to java executable, not directory.
Please check by using:

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
```

It will show you a link, do `ls -l` on the link that it gives you and you will see that it is actually a file not a directory.